# Error when sending double quotes with ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax

I want to let users type in a URL. I want to send that URL to another page on my website using Ajax. On the other page it stores the url in a variable and does something with the url.
The problem: if a user doesn't type in a URL but some double quotes, I get an error.

Code on main page:

```
var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "api/checkURL",
                processData: false,
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: '{"URL": "'+url+'"}',
                success: function(r) {
                        //do something here
                }
})
```

Code on other page (page where I send the Ajax request to)

```
if($_GET['url'] == "checkURL") {
                $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
                $data = json_decode($data);

                $url = $data->URL;

                //do something with the url
}
```

The error I get if someone types in double quotes

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'URL' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\website\api\index.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
```

(line 15 is the line: `$url = $data->URL;`)

If a user types in `https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png` , it works and there are no errors. But if a user types in `"`, it gives an error.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Hans. You should have a look inside of $data to see what's actually there, after file_get_contents and after json_decode. The error tells us that whatever is in $data is not an object and doesn't have a URL property. Try var_dump($data) or just print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify` to create JSON, don't create it by hand. It will escape the quotes properly.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/checkURL",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({URL: url}),
    success: function(r) {
            //do something here
    }
})
```